# MPD templates for MPEG DASH TS content

Tags: vlc

I am looking for MPD templates which can be used to stream MPEG2-TS fragments.

Client is VLC with DASH plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Go http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/dash/public/support-player/current/index.html and change the "Caption Test" to something else. You would get a corresponding .mpd then.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any fragmented content for DASH with video/mp2t mimeType. I looked [here](http://dashif.org/testvectors) but all of them are based on BMFF (video/mp4) so I think that the best option is to generate your own fragments and corresponding MPD. You can use Gpac's MP4Box like described [here](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2012/02/01/dash-support/).

It appears that most of the work that was put into DASH is based on ISOBMFF and not on MPEG2 TS. Maybe because it provides better separation between audio and video, therefore in case of adaptation you have more flexibility. (Using TS you must create muxed content for each configuration).

Answer (score -1):

The public MPEG-DASH standard is available here: [ISO/IEC 23009-1:2014](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c065274_ISO_IEC_23009-1_2014.zip)

See sections 6.4, 7.4, 8.6, 8.7, G.3.

You can also find the schema files here: [MPEG-DASH Schema](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/)